# Tax in Cart/Checkout Totals not expandable

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, checkout

I have been searching the net and especially here for this issue for hours now.

My Totals in the Cart/Checkout show a Tax.Line, but it's only labelled as "Tax". I know there is a setting to get it as "expandable" (with a + in front). Although I have in the settings the "show complete" option enabled, it still does not show any details.
I am especially looking to see the tax rate (%) there. As it is for different countries, it should be automatically, not a hard hack.

Oh, the Tax gets calculated correctly for every country. Just not shown /labelled correctly.

Any idea would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

1. After applying the Tax, delete Cache from the Magento admin and Reindex the data from the Magento admin.
2. If you want to display the full Tax Summary on the Cart Page Navigate to the System > Configuration > Click on the Tax under the Sales Tab Left sidebar Now click on the Shopping Cart Display Settings and Display Full Tax Summary : Yes Now you will see the full Tax Summary on the Cart page.

You can select other options from here.

Hope it helps,

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Had the setting already to yes; flushing cache and re-indexing did not bring the desired change...